# Found at least one incompatible extension during start up

Tags: rapidminer

I'm working on extension development for rapidminer. I downloaded the template project from github https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-extension-tutorial and compiled it successfully. According to the steps in the readme file, I executed installExtension.

[image]

When I start rapidminer, it shows:

[image]

There are only ignore choice, apply can not be chosen. But when I select ignore, the rapidminer opens successfully and loads the extension I just developed. I can also perform custom operators.

[image]

However, some operators failed to execute, seems like permission issues. 
[image]

I guess it's because the extension is considered to be an unsafe or unregistered extension, resulting in the operation can only have a part of the permissions. Because I see this comment in the source code:
[image]

My operator doesn't have any problem, because I test it in extension project. It shows the correct result.
[image]

So Does anybody konw how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant addition permissions to unsigned extension, by navigating to 
Settings -> Preferences
Select the tab "start-up" and enable "Grant additional permissions to unsigned extensions".